# Getting Volume Output from AVAudioSynthesiser in IOS via swift

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I am trying to add a Siri like button to a game I am working on.  I am using AVSpeech Synthesiser and I am trying to create an animation that will move with the speech output volume.

I don't see a method to get the volume output of AVAudiosynthesiser.  Is there a way to get it via another framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution might be to show some visuals by registering an `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` and listening for calls to `speechSynthesizer:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:`

Comment: How would I get a volume from that ?

Comment: You don't get the volume, you just get an indication that there is some sound being output. It's not what you asked for, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This is not a solution but more a hint of what can be done based on experience.

A bit hard to do setup would be to route the sound through AVFoundation core buffers and make a simple Fourier transformation to get the Amplitudes and use the Amplitude as "Volume".

I use a similar technique to visualize in real-time the music played and live recording from microphone input for a karaoke app I made.